# AnimationHandler has changed for threejs, how can I get it working?

Tags: three.js

I created a webgl animation using the threejs library, some time ago, today I have been trying to get it to run on the latest version of the three.js library.

In the latest library, there is no pathcontrols.js.

I copied pathcontrols.js from my old library to the new version, but this has not solved the problem,

Below is the full function that does not work properly, but it is the .add() and the animation() calls where I think the problem is:

```
function initAnimationPath( parent, spline, name, duration ) { 
   var animationData = {
       name: name,
       fps: 0.6,
       length: duration,
       hierarchy: []

    };

    var i,
        parentAnimation, childAnimation,
        path = spline.getControlPointsArray(),
        sl = spline.getLength(),
        pl = path.length,
        t = 0,
        first = 0,
        last  = pl - 1;

    parentAnimation = { parent: -1, keys: [] };
    parentAnimation.keys[ first ] = { time: 0,        pos: path[ first ], rot: [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ], scl: [ 1, 1, 1 ] };
    parentAnimation.keys[ last  ] = { time: duration, pos: path[ last ],  rot: [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ], scl: [ 1, 1, 1 ] };

    for ( i = 1; i < pl - 1; i++ ) {

        t = duration * sl.chunks[ i ] / sl.total;

        parentAnimation.keys[ i ] = { time: t, pos: path[ i ] };

    }

    animationData.hierarchy[ 0 ] = parentAnimation;

    THREE.AnimationHandler.add( animationData );

    return new THREE.Animation( parent, name, THREE.AnimationHandler.CATMULLROM_FORWARD, false );

};
```

it seems that the deprecation of animationhandler.add() seems to be the issue, but I am having difficulty working out how to replace it.

(amongst many other things) I tried replacing animationhandler line and animation line with this:

```
    THREE.AnimationHandler.update(delta);
    return new THREE.Animation( camera, animationData);
```

No joy.  I would like to know how to get the animation started??

Thanks

Comment: so if have found that THREE.AnimationHandler.add(  )    is deprecated, and I am assuming the problem is here, but I cannot find any information about what to replace this line with.